# How to add multiple array outputs to a dataframe?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, dataframe

I am working with probabilities, when I print the output,
it looks as follows:

```
[[4.88915104e-308 1.43405787e-307 2.20709896e-308 ... 3.08740254e-307
  1.68481486e-307 1.72126050e-307]
 [1.64744295e-004 8.66082462e-004 7.66062761e-005 ... 1.85613403e-003
  9.68750380e-004 8.22260750e-004]
 [6.18964539e-004 1.85605606e-003 2.71300593e-004 ... 3.86232296e-003
  2.01921300e-003 2.18304351e-003]],
```

Is there a way in `pandas` to store it as a DataFrame?

Desired output:

**Index**     **Value**

---

```
0                  [4.88915104e-308 1.43405787e-307 2.20709896e-308 ... 3.08740254e-307
                    1.68481486e-307 1.72126050e-307]

1                  [1.64744295e-004 8.66082462e-004 7.66062761e-005 ... 1.85613403e-003
                    9.68750380e-004 8.22260750e-004]

2                  [6.18964539e-004 1.85605606e-003 2.71300593e-004 ... 3.86232296e-003
                    2.01921300e-003 2.18304351e-003]
```

I tried a lot of ways but I get :

`ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 6, placement implies 1`

Comment: Could you provide the code which produces the error you are showing?

Comment: So you want the full values of arrays to be in the DataFrame cells? Why do you want them in a DataFrame, exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible if convert 2d array to list:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':arr.tolist()})
```

Or:

```
s = pd.Series(arr.tolist())
```